# Question about 3-way switch replacement

Tags: wiring

So I've got a three way switch that controls a light fixture. One at the top of the staircase and one at the bottom. You can see the configuration here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W17YX.jpg

I want to replace them with a smart switch, in particular the TPLINK HS 210. In the photos, you'll notice the bottom switch has already been replaced. The problem is that it doesn't work. The flourescent bulbs just flicker. If I flip the top switch, they come on but don't turn off using the bottom switch. I'm not sure how to wire the top interrupter with the smart switch.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why does the other 3-way have two reds and two blacks going to it?good chance it is a 4-way and there is a third switch which also comtrols the lights.

Comment: That's what I thought too but I have no idea where the other switch could be.

Comment: the switch where you did install the smart switch is also an "end of chain" 3-way, so that is the *most remote* 3-way in the 3/4 way chain.  It does not have certain required wires,  so it is not a viable place to install the smart switch.   Finding this third switch is essential.

Comment: I found the third switch, it was hiding behind a bookshelf. Is it even possible for me to control this circuit with a smart switch?

Comment: Sure, 3-way circuits have plenty of wires to handle comm signals, you just might need to use a more expensive smart switch.

Comment: I bought a smart switch designed to handle a 3-way circuit, so I'll try wiring a different interrupter.

Comment: What differs with 3-way circuits is where power enters vs where the lamp exits.  Every 3-way smart switch will work on some of the layouts. Only some will work on all.